# How to find a certain element in the embedded document

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way that will only return the field of the store that has grade B?

I tried: `db.restaurant.find( {"Result.Grade" : "B"} )`
But it will return back all document content with grade B.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First argument in the `find` query is for filter. Use second argument and pass the fields you want to retrieve.

```
db.restaurant.find(
  { "Result.Grade" : "B" },   //filter
  { "Name": 1, "Number": 1 }      //projection
)
```

With the mongodb node driver use [**`.project()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project) cursor method

```
db.restaurant.find(
  { "Result.Grade" : "B" },
).project({ "Name": 1, "Number": 1 })
```

Comment: But I tried this code and it returns { "_id" : ObjectId("5cb219abe6091140f41e27b2") }
instead of name and number :(

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: It still not work...  db.restaurant.find(...).project is not a function :
I am using virtual machine (Ubuntu)

Comment: Your key names having first letter in capital. Updated again have a look and test it again

Comment: It still shows TypeError: db.restaurant.find(...).project is not a function :
@(shell):1:1

Comment: Use the first one. Second one is for mongodb nodejs driver. With mongo shell use the first one.